# Java orkut client, OAuth keys problems

Tags: java, oauth

I am going through the [Read Me](http://orkut-os-client.googlecode.com/hg/README) file of orkut java client, as I am trying to write a orkut standalone application in java. But,

---

**Point #3 (under usage section) of [Read Me](http://orkut-os-client.googlecode.com/hg/README) says that :-**

*`Get OAuth keys for your app`*

Before you can start using the API or run the sample given here, you need 
to get the OAuth consumer key and secret. Please visit the following URL for
instructions on registering your app and getting an OAuth consumer key and
secret.

http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/RegistrationForWebAppsAuto.html#new

The consumer key is usually your site url, e.g. "my.site.com", while the
consumer secret is a cryptographically secure random string e.g.
"Masdsadl213mzza0Y/l"

---

**From where, and how to get these OAuth keys for my standalone test application.
Also, [Registering your web application](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/RegistrationForWebAppsAuto.html#Registering%20your%20web%20application) section, says that, we can also write an unregistered application.**

---

**Point #4 (under usage section) of [Read Me](http://orkut-os-client.googlecode.com/hg/README) says that :-**

*`Install the keys for use by sample app`*

The OAuth related details are stored in java/sample/oauth.properties

Edit the file and enter the consumer key and secret in there. Leave everything
else untouched.

consumerSecret=
consumerKey=

To test if your keys are valid and everything is fine, run the following
command from your console.

cd java/
ant test-auth

This would open an OAuth flow, by opening a browser window. Once you are
through that flow, you should see this messsage on the console.

"*** Authentication PASSED ***"

If you see the above message, then you are ready to run other samples. On the
other hand, if you see a stack trace or some other error message, then
3-legged OAuth failed.

---

**But, if I am not providing values for the two properties, build is getting failed.
How to get test values for these two properties for *my personal orkut java standalone  test client* ,or, it is possible to run the standalone app without these values.**

Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

I have never used Orkut standalone client before, but I can tell you that if you want to access data from Orkut, like any other platforms, there'll need to have an authorization process (to prevent eavesdroppers and hackers stealing "precious" information).

OAuth basically allows client API's to **authorize** the end-user from retrieving data without passing confidential credentials such as email/password fields. I don't think you'll ever retrieve confidential (orkut data) anywhere else.

Facebook, Twitter, etc., can allow developers to access **public** data, such as search but personal data requires authorization, hence why OAuth.

I don't think it's wise to run Orkut without some kind of authorization scheme.

Comment: - But, can't we use direct Client login, as we do for google data java applications.

Comment: What do you mean by direct client login?

Comment: Client login is email/password combination, see http://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/3.0/developers_guide_java.html#ClientLogin